# Contour Detection in Opencv Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, automation, robotics

I have been trying to identify the contours of red colored objects in Open Cv (python 2.7) and we have succeeded in identifying them. But, I want to detect the position of the red colored object (left or right) and I have not succeeded in doing so. If anyone could give me the code or steps to do so, I would be really thankful.

Our current code for identifying red colored objects is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(1):
  _, frame = cap.read()
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  lower_color = np.array([0, 50, 50])
  upper_color = np.array([60, 255, 255])
  mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
  mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
  mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
  res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

  cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
  cv2.drawContours(frame, cnts, 0, (127, 255, 0), 3)
 print cnts
 cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
 cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
 cv2.imshow('res', res)
 cv2.imshow('contours', frame)



 k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
 if k == 27:
    print "release"

    break
 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, You are one step away of getting the position. You can create a [`boundingrect`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) around the contour(s) and then you can calculate it's center to obtain the coordinates of the object.

You can also try [`minEnclosingCircle`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle) That will give you the center and the radius of it. This could be a little more direct to find the center :)

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) you can find a small tutorial of both functions, but in c++.

in python would be something like this

```
...  
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
cv2.drawContours(frame, cnts, 0, (127, 255, 0), 3)
(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnts[0])
center = (int(x),int(y))
radius = int(radius)
cv2.circle(frame, center, radius, (255, 0, 0), 3)
...
```

in this case, center will be the position of your object. This code only takes in account the first contour in the array...

Comment: cv2.circle(frame, center, radius, (255, 0, 0), 3)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float i got this error... could you please gide me on where I have to add the statements in my program.... This is really urgent as I am working on a project right now.

Comment: @AdhityanSridharan What program for this? I already gave you the code to put inside your own code....  I updated the code to fix the error